# Php form handler - date format

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm using a PHP mail handler to send an enquiry foom from my website.

All is working well except that I would rather the date be formatted differently.

Currently it's sending the date as `yyyy-mm-dd` and I would like it to be `dd-mm-yyyy` or a long date such as `dd-month-yyyy`.

```
<?php
$myWeb = "My Website";
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$number = trim($_POST['number']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);
$date = trim($_POST['date']);

$EmailTo = "mymail@myweb.com";

$Subject = "Enquiry from $myweb"; /// Add a subject

$Body = "$name has made an enquiry about: $myWeb\n\n";

$Body .= "Name:  $name\n\n";

$Body .= "Email Address:  $email\n\n";

$Body .= "Contact Telephone Number:  $number\n\n";

$Body .= "Date of Event:  $date\n\n";

$Body .= "$name's Enquiry:\n\n$message\n\n";


if($Subject == NULL) {$Subject = "From $myWeb";}
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $myWeb");

if ($success){ 

header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html','_self');

}
?>
```

Any ideas please how I would change the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw your update:

This should help:

```
$date = trim($_POST['date']);
$newDate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: not reliable. what if the input date is 01-02-03? feb 2nd '03? mar 1st '02?

Comment: Because it's currently sending the date as yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date('dd-mm-yyyy');
```

I don't really see why you need to get the date from your post form, it doesn't make any sense, just generate the date in your php script after the $message var.

Comment: I need the date as it is asking for the date of the party/event

Comment: Yes, but do not generate it as part of your form, generate it right after your form is submitted, just as i advised you.
L.E: i see you got the solution already, with strtotime(), which is enough.

Comment: @twisted: it's an invitation. sending the server-side date is pointless, because it'd send "now", and the invitation is for (say) 4 weeks from now.

Comment: @MarcB - Yup, got the point finally, when i answered the question this specification didn't existed...

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date with $dateComponents = explode('-', $date) then concatenate the components as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Use `php` [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format the date string

```
$firstDate = $_POST['date'];

$formattedDate = date('dd-mm-yyyy',strtotime($firstDate));
```